# Enable auto dial on Polycomm VoIP phone?

Tags: linux, asterisk

I was wondering if it was possible to make the polycomm devices automatically dial out without the use of the "Dial" button. We have user's who are mistaking this for the phone being broken when they try to dial out and if it was setup as dial when 10 digits are entered into the phone. Is it possible to have that configuration in the sip.cfg file in an Asterisk based system?

Thanks to anybody who responds!!

Comment: If a phone requires you to press a key to dial the number (just like mobile phones do) then there is nothing you can configure on another system to change that. As for the problem, I'd hate to see your users try to use more complex technology, such as a toaster.

Comment: Knowing the phone model might help answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got the right section from my sip.cfg, but I don't need to press the dial button:

```
<dialplan dialplan.impossibleMatchHandling="0" dialplan.removeEndOfDial="1"
 dialplan.applyToUserSend="1" dialplan.applyToUserDial="1"
 dialplan.applyToCallListDial="0" dialplan.applyToDirectoryDial="0">
 <digitmap dialplan.digitmap="[2-9]11|0T|011xxx.T|[0-1][2-9]xxxxxxxxx|[2-9]xxxxxxxxx|
     [2-9]xxxT|[2-9]xxxxxxT|*xx.T|1xT" 
     dialplan.digitmap.timeOut="3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3"/>
     <routing>
         <server dialplan.routing.server.1.address=""
         dialplan.routing.server.1.port="5060"/>
             <emergency dialplan.routing.emergency.1.value="911"
             dialplan.routing.emergency.1.server.1="1"/>
     </routing>
 </dialplan>
```